# Data is lost in ParallelFlux when a rail fails

Tags: error-handling, parallel-processing, project-reactor

I am running a ParallelFlux and one of rails fails. I am not able to "recover" it or even process the events that were supposed to go to that rail

```java
Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    .parallel(4)
    .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .doOnNext(e -> {System.out.println("test "+e); if (e % 2 == 0) throw new RuntimeException(e+":"+2);})
    .doOnNext(e -> {if (e % 3 == 0) throw new RuntimeException(e+":"+3);})
    .subscribe(
        goodNumber -> System.out.println("Good number "+goodNumber), 
        err -> System.out.println("Failed number "+err.getMessage()
    );
```

I'd want to process all the data from the range but I am missing the 6,7,8 because their rails are canceled.

The result I am getting is

`test 2
test 4
test 3
test 1
Good number 1
test 5
Good number 5
test 9
Failed number 4:2
Failed number 2:2
Failed number 3:3
Failed number 9:3`

What is the correct way of paralleling the work and do sort of 'onErrorContinue' functionality for each rail?

Comment: Unfortunately I believe the only answer here is "you can't". There's no `onErrorMap()` or `onErrorContinue()` for a `ParallelFlux`, so the only option is to catch any exception that might occur in your `doOnNext()` methods and ensure it's dealt with in that consumer (so doesn't propagate up the reactive chain.)

Comment: Thank you @MichaelBerry. That goes in line with the the answer I found in [https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5108] "the internals of the parallel operators don't leave much option". Although this is about RxJava but it looks like these two projects have quite a few in common

Comment: Yes, they both conform to the reactive streams specification so they will be very similar.